# Percentage finding

Tags: excel, vba

I just want to calculate the percentage as:

```
Range("E7").Value "=(E5/(E5+E6))"
```

this works fine as this is static range. But after this I'm inserting a row like:

```
Range("A1").EntireRow.insert
```

and now the percentage column remains static but I want the formula to shift one row down also as:

```
Range("E8").value = "(E6/(E6+E7))"
```

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce. After `Range("E7").Value = "=(E5/(E5+E6))": Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert` the formula in `E8` is `=(E6/(E6+E7))`. But the first command line in your question lacks a `=` and you should not using `.Value` for applying a formula. You should use `.Formula`, `Range("E7").Formula = "=(E5/(E5+E6))"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use range object to resolve this problem, with range object it will move when you insert or delete row or column.

```
Sub Answer()
Dim percentage As Range

Set percentage = Range("E7")

Range("A1").EntireRow.Insert

percentage.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C/(R[-2]C+R[-1]C)"
End Sub
```